# Does using Smart Response Technology (Z68 chipset) require a UPS to prevent data loss?

Tags: raid, chipset

The Smart Response Technology (SRT) of a Intel Z68 can operate in two modes: Enhanced (Write-through) or Maximized (Write-back). Clearly, the Maximized mode sounds better since it will give you near SSD speed even with a relative small SSD.

The manual ([Last two links on this page](http://www.gigabyte.eu/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3896#manual) ) says the following about Maximized mode:

> In this mode, cached data is written to the accelerated disk or volume
>   at intervals to increase performance. If the cache device is reported
>   as missing or failed and it contained data that had not yet been
>   written to the accelerated disk or volume, then that data will be
>   lost.

To me, this sounds like only when there is "dirty" data on the SSD cache and the SSD fails, data will be lost. A power outage will not cause any trouble since it will write them to the HDDs when the power is back.

However, a test by [PC Perspective](http://www.pcper.com/reviews/Storage/Intel-Smart-Response-Technology-SSD-Caching-Z68-Tested/SSD-Caching-performance) notes the following:

> ..I'd personally stick with enhanced mode unless I was extremely confident in the stability of my system (and had it connected to a good UPS).

So, does this mean SRT requires a uninterruptible power supply to prevent data loss?

**Update #1**

I have now talked to Intel support (using web chat) and this is the outcome:

> *Me*: .... If I have an accelerated system using SRT and there is a power outage, will the ICH/Z68
>   write the outstanding data (that is still only on the SSD and not on the HD) write the outstanding blocks onto the HDD when the power returns? ...
>
> *Victor*: Every device that will work as cache will loose the information on a power failure. In your case the data in the cache ( Solid-State Drive ) will be lost.
>
> *Me*: ... Does this also mean I get a cache problem if Windows just crashes (but the power
>   remains)? Would this also invalid all data inside the cache?
>
> *Victor*: Correct, but the amount of data should not be that much, it will depend in the process that you are doing and the speed of your hard drives.
>
> *Me*: Can you please give me a link or something where this is documented? ...
>
> *Victor*: Unfortunately this information is not posted on the web site, but I will send your request up so that they add it. ....

**Update #2**

I also talked to the technical writer of the last Z68 test in the last [c't](http://www.heise.de/ct/) - he is disagreeing with what the Intel Support said so they will now try to simply test it out. If I have new information, I will update again.

Comment: I really hopped that somebody could dig up some information about this, but so far it really seems that no exact information exist about this issue. Basically @harrymc and CodeBlend are saying the same, so it's impossible for me to choose the "best" answer. I will award this bounty and the answer to CodeBlend since he was first (sorry harrymc).

Comment: In theory, if your system "froze", in Maximized mode, Intel's drivers should still be able to recover the data, since it's on the SSD still. However, if your SSD were to say, instantly fail, you'd lose all the pending write-thru data, forever. Does that make sense? That's why I still run maximized mode, and use Crashplan/etc. for realtime backups of my important files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seem to be a recomendation as opposed to a necessity but you may find issues arise without. From reading the discussion pointsin the comments in the discussion here:

> And yes, a UPS is recommended as having a power outage while it's syncing a few MB of data would be pretty bad. For those folks, the Enhanced mode is probably recommended.

http://www.maximumpc.com/article/features/everything_you_need_know_about_intels_new_z68_chipset?page=0,1

I think the test by PC Perspective's notes say it well. In my experience typically it's servers that have a UPS, not that a single home/client PC couldn't have one especially without a server to backup to but again it just depends how far you want to go / budget / how valuable the data is.

To directly answer your question:

In enhanced mode no but in Maximized mode, to be absolutely sure, yes is the answer

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this would assume that the controller only tries once to sync the data from the SSD to the HD (at least that's what I interpret from the quote). To be honest, I can't believe this is true because what would happen if the HDD has one or more bad blocks? There must be some sort of retry procedures build-in or else any (correctable) HD error could cause the entire system to crash.

Comment: Neither me or @harrymc are experts it seems so we don't have the first hand knowledge, I suppose it is up to you based on articles and research as to how best to configure your setup.

Comment: @TeX HeX: All hard disks contain redundant sectors to replace defective ones. I agree that the complexity of this SSD/HDD hybrid approach probably causes this technology to be less robust.

Answer (score 1):

Since yesterday I can answer this question myself: ***No, no data is lost***.

While moving about 100 GB (10k+ files) from one partition to another (both on the accelerated array), the main power in my house went down. The file move was about 60% done at this time.

Upon restoring power and turning the computer back on, the Intel controller displayed the following during POST:
[image: POST image]

Some lines are missing, but to me this looks like it has detected it has dirty data on the SSD and fixed it.

Checking the files on the new and the old location from my backup I could verify that no file was lost or damaged.

Comment: This was done with Maximized mode?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have first-hand knowledge, but [Intel Smart Response Technology Explained](http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/printpage/Intel-Smart-Response-Technology-Explained/1292) says :

> The two different modes set up the SSD caching in different ways.
>   Enhanced mode is designed for maximum security, reducing the
>   possibility of data loss but also limiting write speed as it writes
>   data to the SSD and HDD at the same time. 
> Maximized mode is designed
>   for optimum performance, writing data to the SSD and only periodically
>   transferring it to the hard drive. This means that if anything should
>   go wrong with the SSD, you could lose some data. 
> The outcome of an SSD
>   failure would depend largely on what the SSD was caching at the time
>   of failure, so it’s difficult to predict how it would affect your
>   system.

It sounds like a power failure could lose the data from the hard-disk, but maybe not from the SSD (the emphasis is on "maybe").

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so this basically means that no UPS would be needed. Because the data would still be on the SSD and upon the next start, it would be written to the HD?

Comment: I don't think so, since every reviewer of this technology that I have seen warns against using Maximized mode when a crash is possible. I would *guess* that the SSD only serves as a "window" upon the HDD, so once the HDD is corrupted then the SSD is also corrupted. If I were you, I would not dare use this mode at all, UPS or not (since Windows itself is also is entirely capable of crashing totally).

Comment: So the advise is to stop using a SRT with Windows and using Linux with a UPS? :-). Just kidding, I think I'm getting your point.

Comment: It shouldn't matter much to SRT whether one uses Windows or Linux.

Comment: A German PC magazine (c't) tested Z68 mainboard two weeks ago and they wrote that Linux does currently not support SRT. A SRT enabled configuration will appear as normal Drive/Raid in Linux.

Comment: For me these are implementation details. The disk firmware will be the same in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using SRT in Maximized mode for 3 years now (one of the benefits of answering a question so long after it's been asked...). I've yet to encounter any SRT-specific problems after power cuts, accidental unpluggings, unintended presses of the reset button, or blue screens, all of which I've had happen a number of times.

On the next reboot after an unanticipated stop, the computer runs through some kind of cache checking process (takes up to a minute, but usually less) and then goes on to the BIOS screen and then to boot Windows. It's my habit to then run CHKDSK, and most times it finds no problem - doesn't seem any better or worse than power cuts/etc. when using an ordinary hard drive really.

So overall I've found the system trustworthy. Of course, this hasn't stopped me keeping backups.